# Font type from Matlab to LateX

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, latex, legend

I want to export a plot/graph from Matlab to Latex. For various reasons, I want the font type 'Arial' in my graph. I got the following:

[image]

As you can see, the font type is different. Everything should be in Arial and I used the following:

```
set(gca,'FontName','Arial');  
fontname = 'Arial';
set(0,'defaultaxesfontname',fontname);
set(0,'defaulttextfontname',fontname);
```

What is wrong? Or do I have to amend it when I export the plot?

Comment: I don't understand the question, none of those font types are different.

Comment: Visually, it looks different. Only ´Frequency (Hz)' has the right font type (Arial), but others are/look different. How do I get the same font size for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [`axes` property documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) you will see the [`'LabelFontSizeMultiplier'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_labelfontsizemultiplier), which is defined as:

> Scale factor for label font size, specified as a numeric value greater than 0. The axes applies this scale factor to the value of the FontSize property to determine the font size for the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis labels.

Applying this to a small example:

```
axObj = axes;
x = 1:10;
plot(x, x, x, 2*x, 'Parent', axObj);
legend('Lab Spectrum', 'Model Spectrum');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');

axObj.FontName = 'Arial';
axObj.LabelFontSizeMultiplier = 1;
```

Yields:

[image: yay]